# spring boot file upload is not working

Tags: java, file, spring-mvc, spring-boot

i am very new to spring boot, i am trying to upload a file i get this error :

```
> Whitelabel Error Page
> 
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
> this as a fallback.
> 
>     Sun Jan 22 21:05:28 MSK 2017
>     There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>     No message available
```

this is my Application.java file :

```
package com.theligue.webservice;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import com.theligue.webservice.storage.StorageProperties;
import com.theligue.webservice.storage.StorageService;



@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(StorageProperties.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        System.out.println("11111111111111111111111111111111111111");
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(StorageService storageService) {
        System.out.println("222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222");
        return (args) -> {
            storageService.deleteAll();
            storageService.init();
        };
    }
}
```

and this is the File uploader controller File :

```
    package com.theligue.webservice;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MvcUriComponentsBuilder;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

    import com.theligue.webservice.storage.StorageFileNotFoundException;
    import com.theligue.webservice.storage.StorageService;


    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class FileUploadController {
        private final StorageService storageService;

        @Autowired
        public FileUploadController(StorageService storageService) {
            System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            this.storageService = storageService;
        }

        @GetMapping("/")
        public String listUploadedFiles(Model model) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");

            model.addAttribute("files", storageService
                    .loadAll()
                    .map(path ->
                            MvcUriComponentsBuilder
                                    .fromMethodName(FileUploadController.class, "serveFile", path.getFileName().toString())
                                    .build().toString())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            System.out.println("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
            return "uploadForm";
        }

        @GetMapping("/files/{filename:.+}")
        @ResponseBody
        public ResponseEntity<Resource> serveFile(@PathVariable String filename) {

            Resource file = storageService.loadAsResource(filename);
            return ResponseEntity
                    .ok()
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\""+file.getFilename()+"\"")
                    .body(file);
        }

        @PostMapping("/")
        public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                       RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

            storageService.store(file);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                    "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");

            return "redirect:/";
        }

        @ExceptionHandler(StorageFileNotFoundException.class)
        public ResponseEntity handleStorageFileNotFound(StorageFileNotFoundException exc) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }


    }
```

> this is the console output when i hit localhost:8080/

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.3.RELEASE)

2017-01-22 21:05:08.319  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] com.theligue.webservice.Application      : Starting Application on DESKTOP-M1QNJT9 with PID 1572 (started by Mohammad Taha in C:\Users\Mohammad Taha\workspace\theLigue\LigueWebServices)
2017-01-22 21:05:08.322  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] com.theligue.webservice.Application      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-01-22 21:05:08.637  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1c13f3d5: startup date [Sun Jan 22 21:05:08 MSK 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-01-22 21:05:11.743  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-01-22 21:05:11.760  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-01-22 21:05:11.763  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
2017-01-22 21:05:11.949  INFO 1572 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-01-22 21:05:11.949  INFO 1572 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3315 ms
2017-01-22 21:05:12.198  INFO 1572 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-01-22 21:05:12.202  INFO 1572 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-01-22 21:05:12.203  INFO 1572 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-01-22 21:05:12.203  INFO 1572 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-01-22 21:05:12.203  INFO 1572 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2017-01-22 21:05:12.317  WARN 1572 --- [  restartedMain] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation should only be used on methods with parameters: public java.util.Collection com.theligue.webservice.service.PlayerService.getFakeDataObject()
222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
2017-01-22 21:05:12.950  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2017-01-22 21:05:13.013  INFO 1572 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:4}] to localhost:27017
2017-01-22 21:05:13.015  INFO 1572 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 1]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=568071}
2017-01-22 21:05:13.334  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1c13f3d5: startup date [Sun Jan 22 21:05:08 MSK 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-01-22 21:05:13.554  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.theligue.webservice.FileUploadController.listUploadedFiles(org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.io.IOException
2017-01-22 21:05:13.555  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/files/{filename:.+}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.core.io.Resource> com.theligue.webservice.FileUploadController.serveFile(java.lang.String)
2017-01-22 21:05:13.556  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.theligue.webservice.FileUploadController.handleFileUpload(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
2017-01-22 21:05:13.559  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-01-22 21:05:13.560  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-01-22 21:05:13.605  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-01-22 21:05:13.605  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-01-22 21:05:13.655  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-01-22 21:05:14.328  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2017-01-22 21:05:14.408  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-01-22 21:05:14.489  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-01-22 21:05:14.498  INFO 1572 --- [  restartedMain] com.theligue.webservice.Application      : Started Application in 6.679 seconds (JVM running for 7.413)
11111111111111111111111111111111111111
2017-01-22 21:05:28.908  INFO 1572 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-01-22 21:05:28.908  INFO 1572 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-01-22 21:05:28.930  INFO 1572 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
```

i noticed that it dose not go to listUpdatedFiles function inside the file upload controller .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class FileUploadController {
```

which means your requests will start with `/api`

to reach the `listUploadedFiles` method you need to hit [localhost:8080/api/](http://localhost:8080/api/)